# Safety in controlling the drone dji m100 with raspberry and ROS

Tags: ros, dji-sdk

I have a question regarding the safety of the raspberry usage to control the drone m100.

I wrote a simple program in c++ for the takeoff and landing of the drone m100. I want to execute this program on the real drone using ROS. Therefore I put this program on the raspberry (along with the dji libraries) and via ssh i can execute it and control the drone. But if someone goes wrong during the execution, can the user regain the control of the drone using the remote controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In our experience, if something goes wrong, you should be able to move the switch on the controller to 'P' and get control of the drone.

Comment: mode 'F' to control the drone with the raspberry, mode 'P' for the user. Is it correct?

Comment: Additonally, I'd suggest you try to implement some safety features as well into your program as well. Take a look at the `FlightAnomaly` Topic as well. Although, I'm not sure if it's available for the M100